# parsing JSON - but some arrays are missed

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to parse a JSON string with the Newtonsoft package.
It's from the "Elite Dangerous Companion" Interface.
Everything seemed to be fine, but now I have ascertained
that two arrays are not existing in the resulting JSON-object.

My code for parsing :

```
String json = response.Json ?? "{}";
JObject m_joCompanion = JObject.Parse(json);
```

You can download [the JSON-string here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/n1v3zv).

The missing parts are

> "lastStarport"-"ships"-"shipyard_list"

and

> "lastStarport"-"ships"-"unavailable_list"

If I parse the string online with 
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
all data is visible.

Anyone has an idea what's wrong or how to get the missing data ?

thank you

Comment: Please post your json in the question, for one it follows the SO guidelines, for two I'm not downloading some random file from some random website. Secondly, can you post the results of inspecting your `JObject`? It seems likely to me that the arrays are there and you're just not sure how to access them. `JObject` should pick up everything, it's not like you're using `DeserializeObject<T>` and have some discrepancy between your model and json which would cause this.

Comment: Sorry, the json string is too big for posting here (119KB).

Comment: Just put the JSON up on something like [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/). It allows up to 512 KB for unregistered users. And if the JSON file is 119 KB it really helps if you point out the line numbers that are causing the problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

next try :-)

ok, I found out VS holds the wrong dll version (don't know why).
However, now I'm working on the correct version (v8.0.3.19514 found in the bin path) - but this didn't solve my problem :-(

I did following for testing:

```
                Debug.Print(m_joCompanion["lastStarport"].Children().Count());
                foreach (var item in m_joCompanion["lastStarport"].Children())
                {
                    Debug.Print(item.ToString());                        
                }
```

and I got this output/hints for the objects:

- lastStarport has 5 children (should be 6!)
- child 1:  "id": "3226125568"
- child 2:  "name": "Tanaka Terminal"
- child 3:  "faction": "Independent"
- child 4:  "commodities": []
- child 5:  "modules": {}

But I got no [ships] data or one of its sub-structures

I have no idea what the problem is. Do you have tips ?

**EDIT:**
I did another thest on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
an switched the standard:

RFC 7159 : 5 children (w/o ships-data)
RFC 4627 : 6 children (ships-data existing)

Can I switch this in Newtonsoft ?

**EDIT 2**

I tried this and it works !

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject>(json);
```

But I still not unterstand why the old version with .Parse()
is not working on my system :-/

Answer (score 0):

Note to others: that JSON file is 7400+ lines long so I don't know if you want that posted directly, maybe OP can post to pastebin or something instead.

What .NET version and version of Newtonsoft.Json are you using? I tried using .NET 4.5.2 and  Newtonsoft.Json version 8.0.3 and i could navigate to those objects just fine.

I ran the following:

```
        var jsonText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\me\Downloads\companion.json");
        var m_joCompanion = JObject.Parse(jsonText);

        Console.WriteLine(m_joCompanion["lastStarport"]["ships"]["shipyard_list"]);
        Console.WriteLine(m_joCompanion["lastStarport"]["ships"]["unavailable_list"]);
```

and it definitely output some data. Is there some difference in encoding or something between what you posted in the file vs your response.Json property?

Comment: I'm using .net 4.6 and the NuGet installer says "Newtonsoft v8.0.3"  
but if I check the properties of the installed "Newtonsoft.json.dll"   
I can only see v6.0.8.18.111.   
Is this correct ?

Comment: Mine says 8.0.0.0 and the runtime version is v4.0.30319. I updated to change the framework to 4.6 and it still seems to work fine. Maybe you need to completely remove the reference and reinstall it via NuGet?

Comment: hm, strange.  I already reinstalled the nuget manager and also the newtonsoft package. I tested your code from above and I get "null" if I try to get  m_joCompanion["lastStarport"]["ships"] !?  I go sleep now, maybe tomorrow is a better day.